# 'Jump' to translateY value then animate back to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I need an element to 'jump' to a `translateY` value **without a transition** and then immediately **animate** back to `translateY: 0`.

Unfortunately, the following doesn't work (nothing happens, because I guess the transform is removed 'too immediately')

```
$('div').css('transform', 'translateY(' + height + 'px)');
        .addClass('animate-transform')
        .removeAttr('style');
```

The following works, but it feels very hacky and I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution..

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  
  var height = 200; // This is not always 200

  $('div').css('transform', 'translateY(' + height + 'px)');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').addClass('animate-transform')
            .removeAttr('style');
  }, 0)

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').removeClass('animate-transform');
  }, 1000)

})
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.animate-transform {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: For a moment I got carried away with your name. I started expecting to get the green card today itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a CSS animation and rely on `animationend` event to remove the class. You may also use CSS variables if you want the translate value to be dynamic.

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $('div').css('--v', '200px');
  $('div').addClass('animate-transform').on('animationend', function() {
    $('div').removeClass('animate-transform')
  });
})
```

```css
div.e {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.animate-transform {
  animation: change 1s;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    transform: translateY(var(--v));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="e"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting idea, however, the 200 is not always 200, so it needs to come from JS

Comment: That's brilliant! I never knew you could do that stuff with `var(--v)`! I would suggest one edit though: using `.one` instead of `.on`, so that there isn't a new event listener for every click, right?

Comment: @TonaldDrump yes if you want but I suppose this is specific to your requirement and not this particular question? .. my solution deals with the animation issue, then using one, on, click, etc will depend on each one needs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSS Transitions you could use Jquery's animation API. Just set the position of the div as `relative` and modify the `top`. Works similar as expected.

```js
var height = 150;
$('div').on('click', function(){
$('div').css('top', height).animate({'top': 0},800);
});
```

```css
div {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
  position:relative;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Refer JQuery Animate: https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use `top` due to performance issues. The application is mobile and there are several divs that I have to animate at once